# ng-options need to be passed as an object value to an array

Tags: angularjs

I need to pass the selected country name into key name `country`, but the `$scope.options` would not be recognized. I cannot select the country let alone pass the right country to the key value. So does anyone knows what I am doing wrong, and what the solution might be in this case.

Anyone an idea how I can fix this?

```js
 $scope.addComment = function() {
  $scope.comments.push($scope.dataObject);

  $scope.options = [{
   id: 1, 
   country: "China"
   }, 
   {
   id: 2, 
   country: "France"
   }, 
   {
   id: 3, 
   country: "Germany"
   }, 
   {
   id: 4, 
   country: "Japan"
   }, 
   {
   id: 5, 
   country: "Hongary"
   }, 
   {
   id: 6, 
   country: "Hong Kong"
   }, 
   {
   id: 7, 
   countrybv : "Italy"
   }]

  $scope.dataObject = {
   name: "", 
   country: $scope.options[0], 
   comment: ""
  };
 };
```

```html
<body>
  <td><select class="comment-form comment" ng-model="selected" ng-options="option as option.country for option in options track by option.id">
    <option value="">Select a country</option>
    </select></td>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select ng-model="selected"               
        ng-options="x as x.country for x in options track by x.Id"
        class="form-control" 
        ng-required="true">
  <option value="">-- Choose Country --</option>
</select>
```

[For more option see](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1196/angularjs-dropdown-select-value-text-multiple-values-with-demo)

Comment: "track by x.Id" should be "track by x.id"

Comment: I know, had already read the documentation, but it could not be linked to the id. That is the main issue of this....Maybe I overlooked something in the JavaScript part...

Comment: What do you mean by $scope.options would not be recognized, seems you are doing something different than you post here

Answer (score 0):

in html:

```
<select ng-model="selectedCountry" ng-options="country as country.country for country in countries track by country.id">
  <option value="" disabled="" selected>Select Country</option>
</select>

<p>country: {{selectedCountry.country}}</p>
<p>id: {{selectedCountry.id}}</p>
```

I've made this in plnkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/406tgmG5L4s5SFEeUlF3?p=info

Good luck!